# Are IO Control codes determined by the hardware or ...?

Tags: hardware-interface

I have a small project (for my cell phone) on the go, and I believe I have found IO Control codes for what I want to accomplish (theres nothing at a higher level unless I can reverse engineer the dlls and call them).

However, the codes are from a different device from a different manufacturer (the board is the same - a snapdragon 8650)

Will those control codes be likely to work on my device, or is that going to be dependent on something manufacturer specific?

Am I likely to be able to do permanent damage to my phone by trying them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer itself is manufacturer-dependent.

Having the same board, chances are at least some of the codes are the same.
And the likelihood of causing damage is low (unless you hit FLASH memory).

I'd give it a go, if it were *my* phone.